# Getting different behavior for different numbers of arguments in a custom command

Tags: vimscript, vimrc, command-line

I'm trying to make a custom Vim command to compile code without having to do `:!gcc -Wall %:p -o %:p:r` every time. So far, I've been using this:

```
:command Com w<CR>! gcc -Wall %:p -o %:p:r
```

But the problem with that is that if I want to compile multiple files, I have to go back to `:!`. I was thinking of something like this:

```
:command -nargs=+ Com w | ! gcc -Wall <args> -o compiled
:command -nargs=0 Com w | ! gcc -Wall %:p -o %:p:r
```

However, that doesn't work, because it throws an error for trying to define the command twice. It does show what I want to do, though, I think.

How can I get different behavior for different numbers of arguments?

---

<sup>I'm new here. Please don't be too angry if I misread or misunderstood [Don't Ask](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and [On Topic](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), or left out some information that's necessary.</sup>

Comment: Try to make a single command, that covers both cases.

Comment: @VanLaser I have, and failed. I currently have it as two commands, `ComC` and `ComM`, for "compile current" and "compile many". Still, it's an interesting question, even if the answer is just "It can't be done".

Comment: How about making a `Makefile` (that has as targets either the whole binary, or just a single object - so it would solve both of your problems)? You will then just have to run `:make` from Vim AND you get any errors in the quickfix window.

Comment: @VanLaser Hm, that could work. The problem is that then, even for my tiny little test things, I have to make a makefile.

Comment: Yes - perhaps have a Makefile template or snippet skeleton ready. There is also [this](https://github.com/vim-scripts/SingleCompile), but only for a single file ...

Comment: BTW, to compile/build a single source file, you don't even need a Makefile. E.g. if you have `test.c`, just run from Vim: `:make test` and "it will be done".

Comment: @VanLaser Huh, that's fascinating. Could you put it in an answer?

Comment: It's too late, I have to sleep, but it's no big deal (it's a property of `make` - the program - it tries to infer building rules).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know nothing about compiling but if I understand you correctly, you want a vim command that can be used without argument to execute a shell command.
And if the same vim command is used with arguments, it should execute a different shell command on them.

I've come up with a template that maybe you could adapt to your specific needs and that seems to do what you want :

```
function! CompileFiles(...)

    if a:0 == 0
        !echo "Compile without argument"
    else
        execute "!cat " . join(a:000)
    endif

endfunction

command! -nargs=* Com call CompileFiles(<f-args>)
```

In this template, the `Com` command is defined at the end and calls the `CompileFiles()` function that is defined just above.

The command passes the arguments it receives to the function.
Inside the latter you can test the number of arguments with `a:0` and access the list of arguments with `a:000`.

The function tests the number of arguments it has received :

- if it's 0 it executes the shell command `echo "Compile without
  argument"`
- if it's more, all the arguments are concatenated (with the built-in `join()` function) into a string which in turn is concatenated at the end of `"!cat "`.
  The content of the resulting string is then executed.
  For example, if you type `:Com foo bar`, the function should execute `!cat foo bar`.

What you want is different.
You want to write the current file (`w`) and then (`|`) execute the shell (`!`) command `gcc -Wall %:p -o %:p:r` if no argument follows the command, or execute `gcc -Wall <args> -o compiled` if there are arguments.

I think the previous code could be modified like this :

```
function! CompileFiles(...)

    if a:0 == 0
        write
        !gcc -Wall %:p -o %:p:r
    else
        write
        execute "!gcc -Wall " . join(a:000) . " -o compiled"
    endif

endfunction

command! -nargs=* Com call CompileFiles(<f-args>)
```

Not sure it will work though.

One last thing, before passing some arguments to the shell it's often recommended to escape them. There's a built-in function that does it : [shellescape()](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#shellescape%28%29)

I know how to use it on a specific argument :

`shellescape(a:foo)` will escape the argument whose name is foo,
 `shellescape(a:1)` will escape the first argument of the optional group (the one that is symbolized by `...` in the previous code), etc.

but I don't know how to escape a list of arguments whose size is unknown.

**Edit** : I've tried to modify the code a little bit to escape the arguments in case they contain special characters :

```
function! CompileFiles(...)

    let mylist=[]
    let c = 0
    while c < a:0
        let myarg = shellescape(a:000[c])
        call add(mylist, myarg)
        let c += 1
    endwhile

    if a:0 == 0
        write
        !gcc -Wall %:p -o %:p:r
    else
        write
        execute "!gcc -Wall " . join(mylist) . " -o compiled"
    endif

endfunction

command! -nargs=* Com call CompileFiles(<f-args>)
```

The only thing that changes is the creation of a `mylist` variable and a `while` loop that executes the `shellescape()` function on each argument received by the main function.

I didn't test it as I don't have anything to compile.